# Not registered IRequestClient in DI

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

For the project with microservice architecture, I created an extension methods for registering MassTransit. Here is an example of one of the two:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransitConfigWorker(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config,
            string nameQueue)
        {
            return services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host(config.GetValue<string>("MqHost"), hostCfg =>
                        {
                            hostCfg.Username(config.GetValue<string>("MqUser"));
                            hostCfg.Password(config.GetValue<string>("MqPassword"));
                        });

                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(nameQueue, epCfg =>
                        {
                            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                            var massTransitManager = provider.GetService<IMassTransitManager>();
                            epCfg.Consumer(() => new RequestModelConsumer(massTransitManager));
                        });
                    });
                    x.AddRequestClient<RequestModelWorker>();
                })
                .AddMassTransitHostedService();
        }
```

A simple service was also created to send a message to the queue and receive a response:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        private readonly IRequestClient<RequestModel> _client;

        public TestService(IRequestClient<RequestModel> client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> SendRequestMessageAsync(string request)
        {
            var response =
                await _client.GetResponse<RequestModelResponse>(new RequestModelResponse { RequestString = request });
            return response.Message.ResponseString;
        }
    }
```

Next, the TestService service is registered in DI, but IRequestClient was null.
Error text:

```
MassTransit.ConfigurationException: An exception occurred during bus creation
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Configuration.RabbitMqHostConfiguration.Build()
   at MassTransit.Registration.TransportRegistrationBusFactory`1.CreateBus[T,TConfigurator](T configurator, IBusRegistrationContext context, Action`2 configure, IEnumerable`1 specifications)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.Registration.TransportRegistrationBusFactory`1.CreateBus[T,TConfigurator](T configurator, IBusRegistrationContext context, Action`2 configure, IEnumerable`1 specifications)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Configuration.RabbitMqRegistrationBusFactory.CreateBus(IBusRegistrationContext context, IEnumerable`1 specifications)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.CreateBus[T](T busFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<SetBusFactory>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__7`1.<SetBusFactory>b__7_4(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<.ctor>b__1_1(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.DependencyInjectionContainerRegistrar.GetClientFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.DependencyInjectionContainerRegistrar.<>c__DisplayClass16_0`1.<MassTransit.Registration.IContainerRegistrar.RegisterRequestClient>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Worker.WorkerEngine..ctor(IServiceProvider provider, ILogger`1 logger, IAccessSecurityService accessSecurityService, IUserContext userContext, IUserInfoStorage userInfoStorage, IDiagnosticsService diagnosticsService, JsonRpcService jsonRpcService) in Worker\WorkerEngine.cs:line 63
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<ConfigureServices>b__5>d.MoveNext() in Startup.cs:line 131
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MassTransitManager.ProcessMessageAsync(String requestString) in MasstransitManager.cs:line 54
   at MassTransitManager.StartAsync(String requestString) in MasstransitManager.cs:line 34
```

**Why am I getting this error?** Interestingly, the second service is identical, and there are no errors in the second service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to put the message type in the request client, not the worker type??

```cs
x.AddRequestClient<RequestModel>();
```

It should match what's used in the test service constructor.

Comment: I found the problem. When I register the MassTransitManager service, it has a delegate to which I pass a new Scope and since it does not have a service in it IRequestClient, then created new ReceiveEndpoint and therefore a new queue. I assume this is due to the fact that the queue name is duplicated.

Comment: is it possible to register RequestClient as Singleton?

Comment: No, you must create a scope to resolve it. If you need to send requests from a non-scoped context, you can call `bus.CreateRequestClient<T>()` using `IBus` as a dependency instead of `IRequestClient`.

Comment: Tried adding `IBus` but got an error  - **An exception occurred during bus creation.** What have I done wrong?

Comment: You're overly abstracting with a "mass transit manager" instead of registering your consumers in the container and letting MassTransit resolve them. It's in the documentation, but you need to use `AddConsumer` and `ConfigureConsumer` instead of creating a service provider in your configuration method. Basic container 101 level stuff.